# Error with importing module named middleware

Tags: django, settings, middleware

After transfering a django project(working) from one server to another, when trying to run the application on the new server I face up the error:

```
Django version 1.11.16, using settings 'geolocator.settings'
Starting development server at http://example.example.com:2000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f23d7ab3668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 146, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 28, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 67, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 44, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named middleware
```

In settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'intranet',
    'bootstrap3',
    'registration',
    'crispy_forms',
    'fm',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'django_crontab',
    'request',

]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'request.middleware.RequestMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

It seems having to do with WSGI but I am not sure what exactly goes wrong.
Any suggestion?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with WSGI. Have you tried commenting out each item in the MIDDLEWARE list in turn, to see which one is causing the problem? And are you sure you are using the same version of Django as on the original server?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the items are ok and the python version is the same. The django version is different. The  old one(working) is 1.10.1 and the new is 1.11.16. Seems that is the issue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the items are OK". Which entry is causing the problem?

Comment: none of the items of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware to find the official list of middlewares.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'request.middleware.RequestMiddleware',  # <-- Remove this one.
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

`request.middleware.RequestMiddleware` is not supported in Django 1.11.16.